# (SOLVED) Magento - Fully disable shipping service

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an operating magento store which doesn't provide shipping at all, can i fully disable shipping (not showing in the "One Step Checkout Page" and more importantly not needing a shipping method or address to confirm the checkout).

I have tried so far to :

- Disable all shipping methods through back-end
- Enable the free shipping method and customize message to " Shipping not available " and not only i get the message under the shipping method tab : *" Please specify the shipping address to see available options. "* but even after putting an address the message doesn't update or anything wich makes the checkout impossible as i need a shipping address/method.
- I checked " Use Billing Address as Shipping Address " OSP settings in the back-end that only removed the checkbox at the bottom nothing else.

Is there a solution so i can fully remove shipping as my store doesn't provide it.

I know that shipping method makes calculations based on address and taxes, but i disabled them and made the calculations based on billing address and not shipping address. Did i make something wrong ?

Comment: You can get this also by set product type to "Virtual Product".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set product type to **Virtual Product**.

So for virtual product type magento default skip **Shipping address** and **Shipping method** at checkout.